# Confusion over Cauchy's Theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

Suppose as the simplest example that I want to integrate: 
$$ \int_{C_{r}(0)} \frac{1}{z+2} \, dz$$, where $C_{r}(0)$ is the circle centred at the origin with radius $r \neq 2$. We have Cauchy's integral formula:

**Theorem:** 
*Let $f$ be a holomorphic function inside and on a positively oriented contour $\gamma$. If $\alpha$ is inside $\gamma$:*
  $$f(\alpha) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f(\xi)}{\xi-\alpha}\, d\xi$$

Thus it seems obvious that we pick $f$ to be the constant function $f(z)=1$ (which is clearly entire). So:
$$ 2\pi i  = \int_{C_{r>2}(0)} \frac{1}{\xi+2} d\xi $$ 
[In the case $r<2$, then by Cauchy's other theorem, $\int_{C_{r<2}(0)} \frac{1}{z+2} = 0 $]

However, suppose I choose instead $g(z)= z+3$ (also entire). Then:

$$ 2\pi i = \int_{C_{r>2}(0)} \frac{\xi+3}{\xi+2} d\xi \implies 2\pi i = \int_{C_{r>2}(0)} \frac{3}{\xi+2} \, d\xi + \int_{C_{r>2}(0)} \frac{\xi}{\xi+2} \, d\xi $$ 
However the integral on the far RHS is equal to zero - recall $\xi(t) = rexp(2\pi i t) $. So we conclude: 
$$  \int_{C_{r>2}(0)} \frac{1}{\xi +2} \, d\xi = \frac{2\pi i}{3} $$ 
And so on and so forth for any $n$. Clearly something is a contradiction here? It seems a really stupid question, but I am very puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

The integral on the far RHS is equal to (again by Cauchy's integral formula):
$$ 2\pi i f(-2)=2\pi i(-2)=-4 \pi i$$

Comment: But if we consider: $ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{r exp(2\pi it)}{2+rexp(2\pi it)} \cdot (2\pi i r)exp(2\pi i t)$ and make the substitution $u=2+rexp(2\pi i t)$, we end up with $\int_{r+2}^{r+2} \frac{u-2}{u} \, du $ ... which would seem to be zero - unless there is some property of the complex logarithm I can use?

Comment: Complex substitutions can be dangerous. Here, as $t\in[0,1]$, $u$ is now $\in\mathbb{C}$, so your limits of integration from "$r+2$" to "$r+2$" actually mean integrate along a circle with centre $2$ and radius $r$ from the point $r+2$ back to $r+2$, so you've effectively just translated the circle and not reduced the problem.